# How can I add new methods to a COM server that I have already registered?

Tags: python, windows, vba, com, pywin32

**EDIT**: turns out VBA can see the new methods if I restart Excel. My question still stands, though, albeit in a different form: how can I force Excel to see the new methods without restarting it?

I have a simple COM server that looks something like this:

```
class COMServerThing:
    _public_methods_ = ["DoStupidThing"]
    _reg_progid_ = "COMServerThing.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{A9DAECC7-2154-42E6-95B3-53A27EAB63E2}"

    def DoStupidThing(self):
        return 'foo'
```

I register it like this:

```
import win32com.server.register
win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(COMServerThing)
```

This lets me create a new COMServerThing object from VBA and call my Python code from Excel. Now I want to add a new method to this server. I've tried doing the obvious thing:

```
class COMServerThing:
    # Add the new method to the list of public methods ...
    _public_methods_ = ["DoStupidThing", "AnotherStupidThing"]
    _reg_progid_ = "COMServerThing.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{A9DAECC7-2154-42E6-95B3-53A27EAB63E2}"

    def DoStupidThing(self):
        return 'foo'

    # ... and implement it on the class.
    def AnotherStupidThing(self):
        return 42
```

After doing this, I still can't access the newly registered method from VBA. Here are some other things I've tried that didn't work:

- I re-registered the server.
- I unregistered and then re-registered the server.
- I unregistered the server, changed the class ID, and then re-registered it.

The only thing that worked was renaming the server, changing its class ID, renaming the source file that the server is in, and registering the new server – at which point we're looking at a whole new COM server.

I'm not a Windows/COM developer, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something blatantly obvious. How can I add new methods to a COM server that I've already registered?

Comment: I usually *kill* the COM object first. Then re-compile the server (the new version), go back to Excel and re-attach references to my COM and it works. I am unable to reproduce your exact problem but make sure you have re-build your COM ( both the .dll and .tlb) properly before reattaching.

Comment: Have you tried both standalone and inproc com servers? I believe to rembeber that one of them worked _better_ with respect to your problem. You need to set one of _reg_clsctx = pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER in the server's definition.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exposing your methods via [IDispatchEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sky96ah7%28VS.94%29.aspx), or are you exposing them through custom interfaces derived from IUnknown?

If you're exposing custom interfaces, then you'll most likely have to restart Excel, since you're breaking [COM identity rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Even with [IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the documentation explicitly says

> The member and parameter DISPIDs must remain constant for the lifetime
>   of the object. This allows a client to obtain the DISPIDs once, and
>   cache them for later use.